# Row by row comparison of many joined tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-10

After a schema migration I need to make sure that all the values in the tables of the old schema have been succesfully copied into the right tables of the new schema. Due to the schemas having a different architecture (different tables with different columns and different relationships with each other), this is taking forever.

This is the method I already have, which should give you a basic overview of the task:

```
for rec1 in(
    select r1.id as r_id, r1.year as r_year...
           f1.id as f_id, f1.year as f_year...
           e1.id as e_id, e1.year as e_year...
           a1.id as a_id, a1.year as a_year...
           ...
    from schema1.table_r r1
         join schema1.table_f f1 on...
         join schema1.table_e e1 on...
         join schema1.table_a a1 on...
         ...
    where r1.id = ...
) loop
    if exists (
        select gbt.id, gbt.ident, gbt.foo...
               gkp.bar, gkp.baz...
        from schema2.table_1 gbt
             join schema2.table_2 gkp on ...
        where
             rec1.r_year is not distinct from gbt.ident
             and rec1.f_id is not distinct from gkp.baz
             and rec1.a_year is not distinct from gbt.id
             and...
             ...
    )then //do stuff
    )end if;
)end loop;
```

I have ommitted a lot of columns, aliases, joins and "is not distinct from" to simplify the overview of the script.

Although this method works, its probably the best example on how not to do it if you have the performance in mind.

How would you improve the performance for this task? I have thought about creating two views, one for each schema, "reconstructing" the tables to be the same, and hashing the rows to compare the hashes between the two views. Would that be a better approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you in the end are trying to compare two tables. If that is the case, couldn't you use a FULL OUTER JOIN? That way you will get the values from each table that differs: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-full-outer-join/

Comment: Yes, in the end I´m trying to compare two reconstructed tables from the different schemas, but for the FULL OUTER JOIN I would need a unique key to join on, right? And I don´t think I have one, because the IDs are different and sometimes the values are almost exactly the same but for one digit in one of the many, many columns

Comment: @Iridium . . . Sample data and desired results  would really help.

Comment: I agree with @GordonLinoff, sample data and desired result would really help! What is it that you are trying to compare. If the data in the source and the target is no longer the same, then you are on mission impossible? You could probably construct keys in both source and target and compare those. Then you need to omit whatever can't be compared.